# Do "especially" and "particularly" mean the same in the following situation? Which is more natural?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

> His hands were chilly and slippery ... especially/particularly slippery.

Do slippery mean the same as particularly in this sentence?

To my ears, "especially" implies that there are two items and that one of them has more weight or is more noticeable than the other. "Particularly" implies that the characteristic is odd in a negative way.

So, to me, "especially" makes more sense. But perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: Are you meaning to ask if *slippery* means the same thing as *particularly* or if *especially* means the same thing as *particularly*? The latter seems more likely, but that's not what you said. I'm also curious what definition of *particularly* you are interpreting in a negative way. Are you perhaps confusing it with *peculiarly*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any negative sense here.  But I think you are not choosing the right adverb. You don't mean "they were especially slippery", but "they were more slippery than chilly".

This makes the sentence in the "slightly odd". How can you compare "slipperiness" with "chilliness"...

I think the adverb you need is "in particular"

> His hand were both chilly and slippery, but in particular they were slippery.

Or you could rephrase more drastically.

> His hand hands were quite chilly, but extremely slippery.
>   His chilly hands were especially slippery.
>   His hand felt as if he had dipped it into cold slime.

Comment: One could also achieve a comparison by minimizing one quality instead of emphasizing the other: "His hands were slippery and a little chilly."